# Which fonts are used in this image?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, web-fonts

Could someone please tell me which fonts are used in 1st and 2nd row of below image?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This is a good site to try to identify fonts. http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ Can be really helpful but sometimes it falls flat on its face.

Answer (score 5):

The sans-serif font is [League Gothic](http://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/league-gothic).

[image: Roll that beautiful font footage]

Here it's overlaid on the image given:

[image: Overlaid]

The tracking is a bit off but it's clear that the glyphs are a match.

As mentioned previously, the other font is [Pacifico](http://code.newtypography.co.uk/pacifico-finished/).

Both are freely available for commercial use on [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/).

Comment: While certainly a close match, they are not an exact match. As evident by the S, the hyphen and the Ps.

Comment: @Johannes Looks the same to me! See my updated image. It's possible that they're using Alternate Gothic (on which League Gothic is based), but given that it's paired with Pacifico, a freely available font, I highly doubt it.

Comment: Yea, this looks like League Gothic to me.

Comment: I stand corrected. :)

Answer (score 2):

The Black And White Phone FONT is **Pacifico**
The App Close-Up FONT is **Equal Sans Demo**
[image]

I am not sure about the **Equal Sans Demo** font. But its almost same like the one you asked.

Comment: It certainly isn't Equal Sans Demo. Look at the S, and the weight.

Comment: ya i am not sure of the Equal sans demo. But I am sure that the other one Pacifico is perfectly matching as the one.

Comment: Not only the S. For every text the weight seems to be low in Equal Sans Demo. May be if you try the same font with Bold, You can get the same one.

Answer (score 1):

Venki has correctly [identified](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/19957/4215) the script as **Pacifico.**

I think the block capitals are **[Trade Gothic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/trade-gothic/bold-condensed-no-20-63882/specs.html),** but I can only find Condensed, not extra-compressed:

[image: Trade Gothic Bold Condensed]

Note the flat sides to C and O, the flat terminals on C and the sloping terminals on S, which has a smooth curve. An extra-compressed version would have a rounder bowl on the P.